# E4000 - [DevExpress.data]: Error: error. dx.all.debug.js:28351 (see screenshot please)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, devextreme

I have always encountered this display upon viewing my Index.cshtml view on the browser. (*refer to the screenshot*).
I created an **ASP.NET MVC 5 app** with **a Web Api** project targeting the .NET Framework 4.8. I added **DevExtreme** to the project and it was all successful.

Now when I add a **DevExtreme DataGrid**, it is ok with no error, but when I run the application in a browser, I see this orange color row with a tag 'error' just above the DataGrid (*see Screenshot please*).

If it is about my layout and the order of loading DevExtreme dependencies, please advise.

**This is a sample of my code:**

```
**_Layout.cshtml:**


    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/DevExtremeBundle")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DevExtremeBundle")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
    <p>© @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<LMS_v1._1.Areas.Admin.Data.Country>()
.DataSource(ds => ds.WebApi()
.Controller("CountryWeb")
.LoadAction("Get")
.InsertAction("Post")
.UpdateAction("Put")
.DeleteAction("Delete")
.Key("CountryId")
)
.RemoteOperations(true)
.Columns(columns => {

columns.AddFor(m => m.CountryCode);

columns.AddFor(m => m.CountryName);
})
.Editing(e => e
.AllowAdding(true)
.AllowUpdating(true)
.AllowDeleting(true)
)
)
```

**DevExtremeBundleConfig:**

```
public class DevExtremeBundleConfig 
{ 
  public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) 
  {  
     var styleBundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/DevExtremeBundle");
     var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/DevExtremeBundle");

     // Uncomment to use the Gantt control
     // styleBundle.Include("~/Content/dx-gantt.css");

     // Uncomment to use the Diagram control
     // styleBundle.Include("~/Content/dx-diagram.css");

     styleBundle.Include("~/Content/dx.common.css");

     // Predefined themes: https://js.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Guide/Themes_and_Styles/Predefined_Themes/
     styleBundle.Include("~/Content/dx.light.css");
    // styleBundle.Include("~/Content/dx.Carmine.css");

    // Uncomment to use the Gantt control
    // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/dx-gantt.js");

    // Uncomment to use the Diagram control
    //scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/dx-diagram.js");

   // NOTE: jQuery may already be included in the default script bundle. Check the BundleConfig.cs file.
   //scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js");

  // Uncomment to use Globalize for localization
  // Docs: https://docs.devexpress.com/DevExtremeAspNetMvc/400706#globalize
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/cldr.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/cldr/event.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/cldr/unresolved.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/globalize.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/globalize/message.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/globalize/number.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/globalize/currency.js");
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/globalize/date.js");

 // Uncomment to enable client-side export
 scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/jszip.js");

 scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/dx.all.js");

 // Uncomment to provide geo-data for the VectorMap control
 // Docs: https://js.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Guide/Widgets/VectorMap/Providing_Data/Data_for_Areas
 // scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/vectormap-data/world.js");

 scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/aspnet/dx.aspnet.mvc.js");
 scriptBundle.Include("~/Scripts/aspnet/dx.aspnet.data.js");

 bundles.Add(styleBundle);
 bundles.Add(scriptBundle);

 #if !DEBUG
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
 #endif
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just added the RouteName attribute to the DevExtreme DataGrid to specify it's route. It worked.

```
.RouteName("routename")
```